# Transporter animation rotation in AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

I have a transporter fleet defined by an agent type that has a certain 3D animation (cube with one open side).  The agent itself is set up to disable animation rotation, as Id like the animation to maintain the same orientation.

When I seize the transporter, unit.isAutomatic...Rotation() shows false as per the agent setup.  However, once the transporter starts moving (MoveByTransporter block) and goes onto a section of path that is a different orientation) the thing still rotates.  Am I doing something wrong here or is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Might be a feature, not a bug.

You can try to override it in your 3D animation properties. Switch to a dynamic value (so it is recomputed all the time) and enter some rad value you want:

[image]

Comment: Thank - would like to think that would work - both in the elements in the agent itself, as well as the agents presentation element in main, but no :(

Answer (score 0):

To quote the very helpful AnyLogic Support - its not a feature of transporters yet (the disabling rotation bit).  Their suggested workaround - which does work - is to basically counteract the rotation as it happens:

In the transporter agent: create a group; add all the drawn/3D elements to it, and then set the rotation to `-getRotation()`.

[image: agent presentation group here]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).